# How can it be secure to append the post id to a html "Like" button and fetching it through jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, security

My entire point is, The end user's browser inspector can change this id when appended and make it look like they have liked some other post.

```
<button id="$post['id']" class="btnlike"> Like</button>

$('.btnlike').On('click',function(){ $(this).attr("id"); /*Push to database with the id received as the post id*/ });
```

While looking into the code of other platforms, I don't notice any particular ids relating to posts. How do the big companies do this?

Comment: They probably use a random string instead.. Instead of 1 /2, they'd use afgsh23hj..

Comment: Is that safe to  do so? That can literally be changed from the browser inspector

Comment: It's safer as it cannot be easily guessed. Anybody can easily change 1 to 2 etc..  But if it's `Ahdhdj69yu` for example, that's gonna be harder if not impossible to guess the next record

Comment: You can just hash the ID's

Comment: How can it be secure to set any `<a>`'s href attribute to anything, ever, when the user can change it using the browser's inspector? My point is, your point is moot. Of course the user can change what he clicks or likes but that does not make it insecure. He does so at his own free will, just as clicking on the link/button in the first place.

Comment: I am not concerned about any other static attributes, the point of concern came from the tutorials of php mysql jquery like button implementation with numeric ids. it is not at all safe in doing so in real applications thus leaving the user the choice to manipulate the code and take effect in the app database @purefanatic

Comment: It's a security risk if user is not allowed to like the second post and no other security mechanisms are in place. But in that case I'm pretty sure the issue would be elsewhere: what prevents the user from liking that other post in the first place?

Comment: Exactly what is unsafe here? Why would you prevent a user from liking some other post? Can you please give us more context about what you're doing? It seems to me like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and that you're either trying to protect your application in the wrong place or trying to protect something that doesn't need protection in the first place.